# How to fix clearRect?

Tags: javascript

Just as an introduction, I'm a beginner with JS so maybe the answer to the following problem is simple but I'm just not seeing it.

I have the following code:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

let img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); };
img.src = './tree.jpg';
```

Which works, so no problem here.

Then I have:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
img.src = './tree.jpg';
ctx.drawImage(img, 730, 720);
```

And for some reason that eludes me, the clearRect doesn't want to work in that sequence.

Any suggestions are kindly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearRect() does not work as intended here since the image hasn't been drawn on the canvas yet. What has happened here is the canvas gets cleared and then the image loads.
As Mozilla says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images),

> If you try to call drawImage() before the image has finished loading, it won't do anything (or, in older browsers, may even throw an exception). So you need to be sure to use the load event so you don't try this before the image has loaded:

Similiar to how you're using drawImage() in the onload(), clear your Rectangle after your image has loaded and been drawn.

```js
img.onload = function() { 
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
};
```